# Why vertx handle traffic better than spring webflux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, vert.x

**Vertx code sample:**

```
workerExecutor = vertx.createSharedWorkerExecutor("test-worker-pool", 200, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
router.get("/test").handler(context ->{
            workerExecutor.executeBlocking(future -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                future.complete("Successful");
            }, false ,asyncResult -> {
                if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
                    sendSuccess(context.response());
                } else {
                    sendError(asyncResult.cause().getMessage(), context.response());
                }
            });
        });
```

**Spring webflux code sample**

```
private Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(200, 10, "MyThreadGroup");

    @GetMapping()
    public Mono<String> getEmployeeById() {
        return Mono.fromCallable(this::handleFile).subscribeOn(scheduler);
    }

    private String handleFile(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3);
            return "Successful";
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

**Result load test use jmeter in minute:**

**Test Plan:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAK0C.png)

**Vertx:**

`Total request: 726320 req/min Throughput: 11194 req/s`

**Spring webflux:**

`Total request: 584532 req/min Throughput: 9564 req/s`

Why vertx handle traffic more than spring webflux?

Comment: Asking about a benchmark result without providing the details is meaningless. What exactly does the Jmeter suite?

Comment: Sr. I added image.

Comment: Most likely because they are not optimizing for synthetic benchmarks of this kind and vert.x comes with a slightly lower overhead (excluding influences from memory, cpu, sun position). Actually this is not relevant in real world application, usually you do something in your request.

https://progressivewebexperience.io/blog/greg_wilkins/2010/06/lies_damned_lies_and_benchmarks